# Is there any useful software for filling out pdf-forms other than Adobe Reader?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have some pdfs that allow me to fill out forms and which also have a print button which is invisible on the printed output. At the moment I have to use Adobe Reader for this, but I'd prefer not to.

I tried Foxit Reader, but with it I can't even fill out the forms. With the standard pdf reader of Ubuntu 10.10 I can fill out the forms, but can't use the print button and when I try to print the document from the menu, the print button shows up in the printed copy, which is useless.

Are there any other pdf-readers which would allow me to fill out forms and use the button in the pdf to print, which would also keep the button invisible in the printed output?

Comment: Evince can fill the form but cannot save the filled PDF document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [Evince Document Viewer](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) (Installed by Default)

[image]

Here is a screenshot of an editable PDF file being filled in my desktop for you to see [Evince Document Viewer](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) in action.

[image]

Like this, there should be some other good PDF readers that will allow you to perform this task, but this is working for me and it is really lightweight.

Good luck!

Comment: To add to what the OP said, Evince can be used to fill out most basic PDF forms, [except for advanced forms that have spell checking, signature fields, etc.](http://live.gnome.org/Evince/ComparingEvinceAcroread).

Comment: This answer was edited by @Alaukik in order to remove my link and to asseverate that this software is installed by default, which is something that I can't say for sure. But I really appreciate @Alaukik's help. Thank you!

Comment: Evince does not work for many PDF forms.

Comment: You're right @JeffBurdges. There are some PDF Forms and some protected forms which can't be filled with evince. For the rest of the forms it does the work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) [image: Install Xournal]

It is not a reader, but a tool to annotate PDFs and other files. It will not execute the form (so no auto-calculation or similar stuff), but it will let you fill (by hand, using a text tool, selecting a font, etc) and print it.

Not the best tool for normal use but really handy sometimes.

Answer (score -2):

You can use "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" along with wine although Adobe discontinued their PDF reader software for Linux several years ago. It works perfect for me.

First install `wine` and `winetricks`

```
sudo apt install wine-stable winetricks
```

Prepare wine to receive Acrobat Reader DC installation:

```
winetricks mspatcha
```

Download the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows 10 from official site http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/

A file with extension exe will be downloaded. (`AcroRdrDC1801120040_en_US.exe`)
Now install that exe file in wine:

```
wine AcroRdrDC1801120040_en_US.exe
```

(Use the same name as that of downloaded exe file)

Click `Install` button.

Wait until the setup is completed and click on `Finish`.

Now search for Acrobat Reader in applications menu and open it.

Select `Always open with Protected Mode Disabled`. (Adobe Reader DC runs in protected mode by default to provide an added layer of security)

Accept Licence.

Now you can open your files using Acrobat Reader DC even on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nice answer, but OP asked for solutions other than Adobe Reader.

Comment: `winetricks mspatcha` fails due to 404 Not Found on W2KSP4_EN.EXE without this the installation fails with "Unimplemented function msi.dll.MsiGetComponentPathExW"