# How to fill out the forms and save the inputs in this tax report pdf file

Tags: pdf, evince, adobe-reader

I am filing tax report for Maryland state using [Form 502](http://forms.marylandtaxes.com/current_forms/502.pdf).

If I use evince 2.32.0 using poppler/cairo (0.14.3), it will recognize the forms and no way I can fill in anything.

If I use Adobe Reader 9, I can fill in the forms, but the software says there is no way to save the inputs unless print out.

So I was wondering what ways can I use to fill in the forms in the pdf file and still am able to save the input and the forms without printing.

Thanks and regards!

P.S. My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: linking for reference (evince now supports this) https://superuser.com/a/1554891/73961

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not mind running wine you can try the free PDF-Xchange viewer from here; 
http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer

This works great under wine, and you can use it to update metadata and annotate pdf documents as well. I downloaded the form and fill in some fields and was able to save it with this application.

Comment: I prefer to run windows applications in Virtual Machine, as you don't need worry about applications' Ubuntu related configurations

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at / considered flpsed PDF annotator?
It should be available in the software centre (universe repository?). 
(At least it is in 11.04).

It's pretty basic but will allow you to add text to a pdf file, useful for 'filling in' .pdf forms.

TIP: Import PDF file and then save as a .ps file until finished adding text. That way you should be able to re-edit any additional text you have entered. Then finally export as .pdf, if you wish, once all data has been added to your satisfaction.

[flpsed home](http://www.ecademix.com/JohannesHofmann/flpsed.html)

Answer (score 0):

With evince 3.10.3 (the version that ships with 14.04 Trusty Tahr), forms can just be filled in and saving the PDF saves the filled in form data with it.

Comment: Can you say more? I've tried clicking on the form and typing, but nothing happens. I can select text and add annotations (that look like sticky notes—not very helpful), but not add text to the form. I'm using Evince 3.28.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" along with wine although Adobe discontinued their PDF reader software for Linux several years ago. It works perfect for me.

First install `wine` and `winetricks`

```
sudo apt install wine-stable winetricks
```

Prepare wine to receive Acrobat Reader DC installation:

```
winetricks mspatcha
```

Download the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows 10 from official site http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/

A file with extension exe will be downloaded. (`AcroRdrDC1801120040_en_US.exe`)
Now install that exe file in wine:

```
wine AcroRdrDC1801120040_en_US.exe
```

(Use the same name as that of downloaded exe file)

Click `Install` button.

Wait until the setup is completed and click on `Finish`.

Now search for Acrobat Reader in applications menu and open it.

Select `Always open with Protected Mode Disabled`. (Adobe Reader DC runs in protected mode by default to provide an added layer of security)

Accept Licence.

Now you can open your files using Acrobat Reader DC even on Ubuntu.

Comment: This approach no longer works for the reasons mentioned in my [comment on your identical answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32862/is-there-any-useful-software-for-filling-out-pdf-forms-other-than-adobe-reader/1037998#comment1775237_1037998)

Comment: It may work with Adobe Reader 11, which can be found on the Adobe FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

PDF Studio Viewer can fill interactive forms:

https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/download/

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice! It works at its best in there, and it's free. From paid software to try, I would recommend MasterPDF ($70 for one-time purchase) and this one: [edit-pdf.pdffiller.com](https://edit-pdf.pdffiller.com/) (subscription, $6 a month). Both of them offering free trial

Edit: didn't notice that's a necro thread with just one fresh answer for the last year, sry

Comment: It's okay https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/17/necromancer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue filling out a PDF and Evince was not saving my inputs correctly.

For me, the easiest way was to simply fill out the form in Chrome and print it to a PDF file.