# Cannot view PDF files with fillable fields with Okular

Tags: pdf, okular, adobe-reader

Most PDF files work perfectly well with my default document viewer Okular, but cannot open a PDF file with fillable field with any program other than Adobe Acrobat Reader (acroread).

Is there anyway to make Okular open, edit and save PDF documents with fillable forms?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/32862/is-there-any-useful-software-for-filling-out-pdf-forms-other-than-adobe-reader

Comment: I've tried many other PDF programs (pdfedit, pdfmod, kword, xournal, envice, abiword) and nothing works... only Acrobat Reader seems to be able to open PDF fillable form files

Comment: can you add a link to your question to an example PDF that Evince and others cannot deal with?

Comment: http://www.uscis.gov/files/form/n-400.pdf

Comment: hmmm - that looks like its hard-coded to only work with adobe reader.  Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Some PDFs have to be edited in Adobe Acrobat Reader only. I had several PDF files with editable elements which were compatible to version 10 of Acrobat, so I had to install the latest reader :)

Comment: Googling a bit shows that many people face the same problem. It must have something to do with the way it's coded. I guess you've probably found an alternative, but in any case, i stepped on this link `www.ussaram.com/N-400.pdf` which seems to provide a valid pdf with fillable forms (I don't know if it's valid/updated though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer as of now is No.

This file is encrypted and can only be opened with Acrobat Reader.

```
richard@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ pdfinfo n-400.pdf 
Title:          Appication for Naturalization
Author:         USCIS
Creator:        Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 8.2
Producer:       Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 8.2
CreationDate:   Thu Nov 15 16:21:11 2007
ModDate:        Tue Jun 21 11:36:34 2011
Tagged:         yes
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      yes (print:yes copy:no change:no addNotes:no)
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      110428 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
```

The only unencrypted element is the following text, found using pdftotext

```
richard@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ pdftotext n-400.pdf l.txt && cat l.txt 
To view the full contents of this document, you need a later version of the PDF viewer. You can upgrade
to the latest version of Adobe Reader from www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html
For further support, go to www.adobe.com/support/products/acrreader.html
```

There are lots of people affected by this.

My solution was to install acroread, fill in and print the form (the option to save wasn't available either for the form I was using), and then remove acroread.

Comment: This shows that this form is not a PDF form, but an XFA document (entries for Creator and Producer). XFA is the forms technology Adobe acquired some years ago with Accelio/Jetforms. It is essentially an XML-based forms format, which gets, in order to be usable with Adobe Acrobat/Reader in a PDF wrapper (this is "legal" according to ISO 32000). To display such a form, you will need a PDF viewer which understands XFA (which is at the moment Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader). If you want to blame someone, blame the forms owner to use proprietary technology.

Comment: Removing acroread is IMHO a rather dumb decision, because aside of the XFA forms, there are many smart forms out there for which the "other" PDF viewers are too dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Fill it out with Okular or EVince then fix it up with PDFTK. Many steps but it works. This may also be a workaround for OS X Preview.app form filling.

```
okular form.pdf
pdftk form.pdf generate_fdf output form.fdf
pdftk form.pdf fill_form form.fdf output filledform.pdf
mv filledform.pdf form.pdf
```